# Python dictionary random output of items

Tags: python, database, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving data from firebase as a list of dictionary. When I printed the list, it's not in the same order.

For example:

```
print(list(mydictionary.keys())[0])
```

This 0 element is always different, print is giving different outputs. I want to print with the same order in the database or make it the same when I took the data first as a list. Is it possible?

Comment: Dict cannot assure you the order. How do you exactly get the data from firebase? Try storing keys in list while you getting the data from firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `sorted()`

`s = {0:1,h:t,1:1,10:2,2:1}
for key,val in sorted(s.items()):
    print key, val`

or in your case

`print(sorted(list(mydictionary.keys())[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) object, which preserves the order of keys as they are added. In python2.7+ this is part of the `collections` module:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = OrderedDict()
>>> a['blah'] = 4
>>> a['other'] = 5
>>> a['another'] = 6
>>> print(a)
OrderedDict([('blah', 4), ('other', 5), ('another', 6)])
>>> print(dict(a))
{'another': 6, 'blah': 4, 'other': 5}
```

I have no experience with firebase, so this answer could be unhelpful in this specific usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve order, use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keys = list("1234")
values = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

order_preserving_dict = OrderedDict(zip(keys, values))
```

As to why the dictionary is not preserving order, I can explain, but its better you take a look at [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)